# gradle: command not found while executing on remote machine

Tags: java, macos, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

I want to execute gradle commands on remote machine which has mac OS. I have written Java program and using JSch library. I'm able to execute other commands like pwd, ls, etc. But when I execute any gradle command it says

```
Connected
bash: gradle: command not found
exit-status: 127
DONE
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 8 seconds)
```

I have already set GRADLE_HOME path in profile and I'm able to execute command from terminal but not from remote program.

Following is my Java program

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package commandexecuter;

import com.jcraft.jsch.Channel;
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelExec;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

/**
 *
 * @author dgulhane
 */
public class CommandExecuter {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String host = "abc.xyz.com";
        String username = "Admin";
        String password = "123456";
        String command = "gradle -v";


        try {
            java.util.Properties config = new Properties();
            config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            JSch jSch = new JSch();

            Session session = jSch.getSession(username, host, 22);
            session.setPassword(password);
            session.setConfig(config);
            session.connect();
            System.out.println("Connected");

             Channel channel=session.openChannel("exec");
            ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(command);
            channel.setInputStream(null);
            ((ChannelExec)channel).setErrStream(System.err);

            InputStream in=channel.getInputStream();
            channel.connect();
            byte[] tmp=new byte[1024];
            while(true){
              while(in.available()>0){
                int i=in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
                if(i<0)break;
                System.out.print(new String(tmp, 0, i));
              }
              if(channel.isClosed()){
                System.out.println("exit-status: "+channel.getExitStatus());
                break;
              }
              try{Thread.sleep(1000);}catch(Exception ee){}
            }
            channel.disconnect();
            session.disconnect();
            System.out.println("DONE");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

I want to know how can I execute gradle commands remotely

Comment: gradle is an external program and probably it is not installed on the remote machine

Comment: @elefasGR is right, but the standard practice in the gradle world is to include a gradle wrapper with source. As long as the remote machine has internet access, the wrapper script will download gradle binaries and execute the build. Using the wrapper also guarantees the the design time version of gradle will be always be used for build.

Answer (score 0):

If `gradle` is not installed on the remote machine then you need to use the `Gradle Wrapper`.  The gradle wrapper is a script like you described that will download and setup gradle.  However the `gradle` command your using `String command = "gradle -v";` refers to the `gradle` binary not the wrapper script.

To call the wrapper script you probably want to use

```
String command = "./gradlew -v";
```

Be sure your command env is set to the base of your project where the script `gradlew` exists.

Comment: The command should include a slash: `./gradlew -v` (unless `gradlew` is in `PATH`).

Comment: @JBirdVegas  I have already installed 'gradle' on remote machine and included 'gradle' in 'PATH'. I will try with  'gradle wrapper.'